# Getting value from apex_item.text

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a classic report with the following example query:

```
select apex_item.text(1,book.title,30,30,' readonly="readonly" ','P4083_BOOKTITLE') as  "booktitle"
from book;
```

I would like to retrieve the value of this page item in a plsql proces:

```
declare
  pl_booktitle varchar2(255);
begin
  pl_booktitle := v('P4083_BOOKTITLE');
  apex_debug.message('Book Title:'|| pl_booktitle);
end;
```

However when debugging it only shows: 'Book Title:' ... and not the value of the page item.

In Session -> Page Items, I cannot find P4083_BOOKTITLE.

Should I set the items before I can retrieve the value? And how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your process? Dynamic action or page process? apex_item used within  a report does not define page items you can interrogate using v()

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
enter code here
declare
pl_booktitle varchar2(255);
begin
pl_booktitle :=:P4083_BOOKTITLE
apex_debug.message('Book Title:'|| pl_booktitle);
end;
```